# How to merge tables without data movement if there is no proper partition key

Tags: sql-server, partitioning

TABLES

```
random_data ( Blank )
random_data_temp1 ( 5 million rows )
random_data_temp2 ( 5 million rows )
random_data_temp3 ( 5 million rows )
```

I want to consolidate all data from _temp# tables into 'random_data'.
If the data in _temp# tables are not sorted and there is no PK to specify a Partition range, then is there any way for me to merge those tables into ONE table(random_data)?
Data movement should not happen.

Any input would be very appreciated. Thanks.

Purpose

Once done, I just want to use the table 'random_data' only. The other tables _temp# will be dropped.

Comment: *Data movement should not happen.* what should that mean??

Comment: You could use EXCEPTS instead of a MERGE.  This will compare the data between the two schemas.